# How to get the last year value based on filter selection?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to get the last year value-based no filter value I selected. For example, if I selected 2019 on the filter, I want to get 2018 values (See picture below). I have a formula, but it will give me blank, Not sure whats wrong with. Can anybody please help me to get this? (Right now I am getting nothing, just blank)

```
Last Year = 
VAR LastYear = 
CALCULATE(
    [Line Amount (Formatted)], 
    FILTER(
        'Calendar - Fiscal Date',
        'Calendar - Fiscal Date'[FiscalYr Year Number] = 
                SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar - Fiscal Date'[FiscalYr Year Number]) -1
    )
)

return LastYear
```

My Data
[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: did you checked DAX function PREVIOUSYER? more details- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousyear-function-dax

Comment: @mkRabbani, I tried. I am not sure how to reference not year on the filter. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Do you have any "Date" column in table 'Calendar - Fiscal Date'? that case you can use that column for referencing PREVIOUSYEAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked DAX function PREVIOUSYER? You can check more details [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousyear-function-dax)

You can also try this below adjusted measure-

```
Last Year = 

VAR LastYear = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar - Fiscal Date'[FiscalYr Year Number]) -1

VAR LastYearValue = 
CALCULATE(
    [Line Amount (Formatted)], 
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar - Fiscal Date'),
        'Calendar - Fiscal Date'[FiscalYr Year Number] = LastYear 
                
    )
)

return LastYearValue
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Any Idea why my way is not working? I am really confused tho.

Comment: Nice to see it worked. you can also put an up vote if it really helped :)

Comment: Your case, you were calculating on filtered data. When you selected a year filter for say 2019, data is only available for year 2019 and you are adding another filter Year = 2018. As a result you were getting nothing.

Comment: I just added ALL(table name) - which is basically clearing all filter context from the data source and now all years data is available. Then the filter Year = 2018 only keeping that year's records and you are getting correct result.